# in openScad GUI is echo() without quotes and ECHO: possible?

Tags: echo, openscad

In openScad 2021.01 (W10) with `echo()` I print  in the console-pane of the GUI statistics and statements to use in scripts. The result is like: ECHO: "hello world". So I must strip quotes and ECHO: with something like `sed`. The latest comment on this issue I found: "There might be an actual output window at some point, but there are no plans on changing echo() ..." (https://issueexplorer.com/issue/openscad/openscad/2036) (). Does anybody know of recent developments here?

Comment: Nobody has picked up that topic (or at least not publicy announced it).

Comment: I wonder if it is not as simple as to just ommit some characters?

Comment: No, only if we would accept breaking workflows relying on the current behavior and there's a number of bigger projects using this, e.g. for BOM generation and other automation.

Answer (score 0):

My question considered an echo output in many lines. Now I see a better way by doing the calculations in one function (by list processing) to separate it from the actual drawing. So instead of:

```
module draw( /*calculate-and-draw*/ );
```

I use now:

```
function calc( /*calculate*/ );
module draw( /*draw this result:*/ calc());
echo(calc()); /* optional; generates one echo in one long list */
```

taking advantage from the fine functional approach by openScad.